# Как найти частичное совпадение строки?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Пробовал использовать алгоритм Левенштейна, но он зависит от длинны строки.

Пример:

```
let c = "1"
let b = "1"
let bb = "12"
let bbb = "123"

console.log(aza(c, b)); //100
console.log(aza(c, bb)); //50
console.log(aza(c, bbb)); //33


function aza(firstString, secondString, round = true) {
    import leven

    //Calculate leven distance.
    const levenDistance = leven(firstString, secondString);
    //Find longest string.
    const longestString = Math.max(firstString.length, secondString.length);
    //Calculate in percentage.
    const result = (longestString - levenDistance) / longestString * 100;
    return round ? Math.round(result) : result;
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы во всех вариантах было 100, так-как там есть искомая строка.
P.S Там, в примере `"1"`, что выглядит глупо. Его я взял лишь для наглядного отображения процентов.

В реальной задаче там будет что-то на подобии:

```
const string1 = "4185614171";
const veryVeryLongText = "И тут длинный текст со значением, 41856AA4171";
```

Соответственно, нужно четко понять, что содержимое `string1` есть в `veryVeryLongText`, в процентах, к `string1`.

Comment: Что-то на подобии, да. Только подстрока может быть разорвана каким-то "мусором". Например "АА", как я показал выше.

Comment: Решение в лоб: сделать из строки регулярку `/4.*?1.*?8.*?5.*?6.*.../`

Comment: Ничего идея. Но, если, например, "5" не будет, - не сработает. (Имею дело с распознаванием текста (tesseract)). А распознать он может очень приблизительно... Например: 4, 5, 7

Comment: Чем вас не устроили существующие реализации? Например, https://github.com/gustf/js-levenshtein

Comment: что значит `есть искомая строка`? Вот, например, `123` и `1 aaaaaaaaaa 2 bbbbbbbb 3` - тут есть искомая строка?

Comment: какой процент совпадений будет между `123` и `321`?

Comment: Между 123 и 321? 100% По другому не получится...